# How to Identify L2 Bridge Transfers?

Tags: etherscan, coinbase, l2

How can one identify if a transaction is an L2 bridge transfer based on the L2 data? For instance, in this [transaction](https://basescan.org/tx/0xdf520b97cfb182468e4a163578031062d7e567518a0ba721633020efcbc9a316), though it appears as a 30 ETH transfer within the Base chain where from and to wallet are the same, I'm not sure if this is enough to conclude. The [L1 deposit](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc38431ce29ee6c0b5938195c877ee3c18ef1b6e0a646bbc501adb4cb8cd86d88) is available, but I prefer not to rely on it. Could the absence of fees indicate that this is an L2 bridge transaction?